# Swagger Version - fabric-hawtio-swagger

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm using Jboss Fuse 6.3 and having problem to use hawtio-swagger.
Only works with version of swagger spec 1.2 (DefaultCamelSwaggerServlet), but when using camel-swagger-java:2.17.0.redhat-630187 doesn't work.

Using DefaulCamelSwaggerServlet (camel-swagger)

```
<osgi:service id="httpServletService" interface="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" ref="swaggerServlet">
    <service-properties>
        <entry key="alias" value="/api-docs/*"/>
        <entry key="init-prefix" value="init."/>
        <entry key="init.cors" value="true"/>
        <entry key="init.base.path" value="ati-nta/rest"/>
        <entry key="init.api.path" value="/api-docs"/>
        <entry key="init.api.title" value="ATI NAJ API"/>
        <entry key="init.api.version" value="1.0.0"/>
        <entry key="init.api.description" value="ATI - NAJ REST service"/>
    </service-properties>
</osgi:service>

<bean id="swaggerServlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.swagger.DefaultCamelSwaggerServlet"/>
```

Using camel-swagger-java:

```
restConfiguration().contextPath("/ati-nta/rest").component("servlet").dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
    .host("0.0.0.0").port(8181).apiContextPath("/api-docs")
    .apiProperty("init.base.path", "ati-nta/rest")
    .apiProperty("init.api.path", "/api-docs")
    .apiProperty("init.api.description", "Serviços de consulta NAJ - www.gestaonaj.pe.gov.br")
    .apiProperty("api.title", "NAJ REST service")
    .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
    .apiProperty("cors", "true");
```

Works with swaggerServlet

[image]

[image]

Doesn't work with camel-swagger-java

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a reproducer application which we can refer and check this ?

Comment: Hi @ViralGohel, you find the example project [here](https://github.com/renalexster/swagger-example)

Comment: Hi Renato, is the issue resolved ? I am taking a look at this.

Comment: Hi @ViralGohel this issue keep not working yet. I updated the images and github detailing step by step to reproduces the issue

Comment: I think that it's incompatibility version with hawtio-swagger-ui and swagger spec 2.0, but i didn't confirmed.

Comment: Hi Renoto, i will check to see if we have a camel issue here and get back to you with more updates. Thanks for the reproducer. This will help.